# Select data from a Datashader plot

Tags: holoviews, datashader, pyviz, holoviz

I'm using Datashader to make crossplots of different parameters due to the quantity of data I'm working with. My idea is to enable some kind of interaction that allows the user to select directly from the plot, the outliers based on the data's tendency showed these ones. I wonder if Holoviews Selection1D stream is compatible with datashader.

This code simulates what I meant:

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews import streams
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade
hv.extension('bokeh')

# Tools to select data
opts.defaults(opts.Points(tools=['box_select', 'lasso_select']))

# Random points to plot
random_points = hv.Points(np.random.randn(1000))

# Holoviews
selection = streams.Selection1D(source=random_points)

# Selected points by Holoviews selection stream
selected_box = hv.DynamicMap(lambda index: random_points.iloc[index],
                             kdims=[], streams=[selection])

# Final Overlay
Overlay = (random_points * selected_box).opts(padding = 0.01)
Overlay
```

So far so good, whenever I call `selection` I get a matrix compounded by the index of the selected points. After Calling the Datashader plot with `datashade(Overlay)` , the interaction between random_points and selected_box breaks, therefore I'm not sure if this stream is compatible with datashader or if the way I use the stream is wrong!

This is what inspired my idea:
http://holoviews.org/reference/apps/bokeh/selection_stream.html#bokeh-gallery-selection-stream

Comment: New releases will make this way, way easier, but for now you can follow the approach in https://examples.pyviz.org/glaciers/glaciers.html to select an area on any plot (datashaded or otherwise) and reflect that in other plots.

Comment: Helpful example to see the possibilities. Now I know it's not necessary to extract the data from the plot... I could just do another plot using streams (dynamic map)

Answer (score 0):

Helpful example to see the possibilities. Now I know it's not necessary to extract the data from the plot... I could just do another plot using Dynamic maps and streams, either by bounds or selection1D.

Comment: Right. That's the key idea -- you can select by axis ranges on any plot, then filter any plot by those ranges, without having to enumerate what might be a very large number of selected data points.